# How to implement Spotify API

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk, spotify

I'm building an music app for android. I have added the C library into eclipse alongside my app. The library is made for android, but it is written in C. I'm unsure on how to convert the C code into the native Android code. If anyone can help me with entering the library's code into my app it will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You might get answers to your question if you explain what you have tried, and where you are having trouble.

Comment: I've downloaded libspotify for Mac and Android. Attempted to install it with no success.

Comment: Looks like it's a library. Do you know anything about native development and/or Java-Native interfaces? If not, the learning curve is going to be steep, and probably exceeds the scope of this site.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: Do you know anything about JNI wrappers?

Comment: Yes. Plenty on google, too, like this one: http://thebreakfastpost.com/2012/01/21/wrapping-a-c-library-with-jni-introduction/

Comment: This is informative, however it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The C header file included contains all of the code for the library. Unlike the example in the post from the website.

Comment: If you only need search functionality you can use the Web API https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the main objective for Spotify to release this API is to identify talent.
People strongest in the combination of expressing interest and making results will
come to their attention.

In case of Android you could for example compile your own Android OS build, create JNI calls between Android and the native library and produce a showcase scenario of music usage for Spotify to consider.
If they like what they see/hear they might want to engage you in some way.

As a sample; one big Spotify thing I would suggest would be to allow end users to contribute Wikipedia-like annotations about artists/songs. People out there are immensely knowledgeable about all sorts of music represented on Spotify and could contribute lots of artist/song info that if compiled smartly could become an awesome asset of Spotify and its suppliers.

A question would be in what way incentives could be offered to such contributors since Spotify or the music company behind a song would much likely have to assume ownership of the contributed info.

Lots of ideas possible on how to develop services that make Spotify an even richer service.